# unable to build and deploy any sample cascades applications to the simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

I have the latest (as of 5/1/2013) SDK and Simulator installed (10.1.0.1483).
I have also downloaded the samples from github and unzipped on my PC.

Here are the steps I take in attempt to launch a sample application:

1. I Launch the Simulator and select the (2) option for BB10 All-Touch
2. I Launch the Momentics IDE

   File -> Import -> BlackBerry (Existing Code...) -> Next ->

   Code Location: C:\Users\Michal\Documents\Cascades-Samples-master\hellocascades

   Language: C++

   -> Finish
3. In Project Explorer -> right-click hellocascades -> Build Configurations -> Set Active -> 5-Simulator-Debug
4. I press the arrow next to the green 'Run As' button -> Run Configurations -> Launch Group -> BlackBerry C++ Application (hellocascades-Simulator-Debug appears in the dropdown) -> Add New Target (In the Main Tab) -> Auto-Discover (I choose the IP address of the simulator) -> Finish ->
   I highlight the IP address in the Target Options -> Apply -> Close
5. In Project Explorer -> right-click hellocascades -> Build Project

   **** Build of configuration Simulator-Debug for project hellocascades ****

   make -j4 Device-Debug 
   make -C .//translations -f Makefile update
   make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/420mj.png): Entering directory `C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations'
   C:/bbndk/host_10_1_0_212/win32/x86/usr/bin/lupdate hellocascades.pro
   Updating 'hellocascades.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   Updating 'hellocascades_en_GB.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   Updating 'hellocascades_fr.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   Updating 'hellocascades_it.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   Updating 'hellocascades_de.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   Updating 'hellocascades_es.ts'...
       Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
   make[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations'
   make -C .//translations -f Makefile release
   make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/420mj.png): Entering directory `C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations'
   C:/bbndk/host_10_1_0_212/win32/x86/usr/bin/lrelease hellocascades.pro
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades_en_GB.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades_fr.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades_it.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades_de.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   Updating 'C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations/hellocascades_es.qm'...
       Generated 1 translation(s) (0 finished and 1 unfinished)
   make[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/translations'
   make -C ./arm -f Makefile debug
   make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/420mj.png): Entering directory `C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/arm'
   make -f Makefile.Debug
   make[2]: Entering directory`C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/arm'
   qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,C:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/qt4/lib -o o.le-v7-g/hellocascades     -LC:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib/qt4/lib -LC:/bbndk/target_10_1_0_1483/qnx6//usr/lib/qt4/lib -lbbcascades -lQtDeclarative -lQtScript -lQtSvg -lQtSql -lsqlite3 -lz -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lsocket -lQtCore -lm -lbps 
   cc: no files to process
   make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/arm'
   make[2]: *** [o.le-v7-g/hellocascades] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory`C:/Users/Michal/Documents/Cascades-Samples-master/hellocascades/arm'
   make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/420mj.png): *** [debug] Error 2
   make: *** [Device-Debug] Error 2

   **** Build Finished ****

[image]

After trying to run it (Green button -> Run hellocascades-Simulator-Debug):

The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist
C:\Users\Michal\Documents\Cascades-Samples-master\hellocascades\x86\o-g\hellocascades not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to get the hellocascades project built and running/deployed on the BlackBerry Simulator.

---

Perform step 1 as your outlined.

For your step 2 try:

File -> Import -> General (Existing Projects into Workspace) -> Next ...

Browse for the 'hellocascades' project folder -> Finish

---

Once you have the project imported into the IDE, follow your step 3:

In Project Explorer -> right-click hellocascades -> Build Configurations -> Set Active -> 5-Simulator-Debug

and then..

In Project Explorer -> right-click hellocascades -> Build Project

---

Continue on with your step 4 and click on 'Run' within the 'Run Configurations' environment after you have inputted the proper settings/fields.

---

After you click on 'Run' the application is automatically built and deployed over to the BlackBerry simulator

Comment: Importing the project differently as you have suggested helped. Thank you!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me until I did a "svn revert -R ." It was necessary as the previous import seemed to have made changes to the project.

Comment: `Build Configurations -> Set Active -> 4-Simulator-Debug` helped in my problem

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this problem in subsequent projects, do `git diff` between the two commits which were working and the first broken commit. From the DIFF file, figure out the classes added to the project. Make sure that for every class, the corresponding library is added in the `.pro` file.

For example
If a class under the `bb/system` directory is added, make sure to include `LIBS += -lbbsystem` in your `.pro` file